# iOSバインドライブラリを参照するとiOSアプリが起動できない

Tags: ios, xamarin

ネイティブのSDKをiOSバインドライブラリを介して
Xamarin.iOSプロジェクトで参照して使用したいと考えております。

MacのVisual Studioで
iOSバインドライブラリをビルドし、生成されたDLLを
Xamarin.iOSプロジェクトで参照設定に追加しました。
DLLに含まれるinterfaceをコードを記述してデバッグ実行すると、
起動画面が表示されてすぐにアプリが終了してしまいます。

iOSバインドライブラリでenum型など一部の定義のみでDLLを作成した場合は
アプリが起動できるケースもありますが、
そうでない場合はアプリが終了します。例外も特に発生しません。

どのような対応方法があるかご教授いただければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

開発環境
Windows 10
Visual Studio 2017 15.9.15
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK 12.4.0.64
Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/205932

Answer (score 0):

参考となるソースが見つかり、そのソースを使用することで正しく起動できるようになりました。
原因がはっきりしないのですが、iOSバインドライブラリでDLLを作成するのは結構難しいようです。